# Preloading with Web Audio Api and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api

I've been working with the [Web Audio Api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/), and this is what I have working so far to load/buffer sound files.

```
function loadSound(url) {
            // Load buffer asynchronously
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            request.onload = function() {
                // Asynchronously decode the audio file data
                context.decodeAudioData(
                    request.response,
                    function(buffer) {
                        if (!buffer) {
                            console.log('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                            return;
                        }
                            window.kick = buffer;
                    }
                );
            }

            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log('error loading file data: ' + url);
            }

            request.send();
        }
```

My issue however, is that I am trying to turn `window.kick` into a parameter in the loadSound function. Such as `loadSound(url, sourceName)` where `sourceName` would take over `window.kick`. The end goal is to play the sound by name with something like `note(sourceName);` (which is working at the moment with `note(kick);` and the above code)

The reason for doing this is I have to load sounds at different times throughout the application, and they cannot be loaded all at once. They then need to be called by name after, unlike [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/js/buffer-loader.js) which is called by index, and called at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadSound(url, sourceName) {
            // Load buffer asynchronously
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", url, true);
            request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

            request.onload = function() {
                // Asynchronously decode the audio file data
                context.decodeAudioData(
                    request.response,
                    function(buffer) {
                        if (!buffer) {
                            console.log('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                            return;
                        }
                            window[sourceName] = buffer;
                    }
                );
            }

            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log('error loading file data: ' + url);
            }

            request.send();
        }
```

Comment: nope, still returns `null` and "Uncaught TypeError: Value is not of type AudioBuffer" when i try to call it outside of the loadSound function

Comment: This is the correct solution however to call the function sourceName needs to be escaped with quotes such as `loadSound("samples/kicks/bouncy.mp3", "kick");` to work in this manner.

Comment: Also the variable itself needs to be global if that wasn't implied.